# Remove "?repeat=w3tc" from any url

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

Some how W3 Total Cache produce on some pages this prefix "?repeat=w3tc". And I really want to remove this from my urls, but my research didn't help me.

Edit: I'm using other plugins now - [The loading times are still good](https://en.instacker.com/article/geography-id=184), I think.

Comment: Just to be more precise: can you explain the reason you don't want it to be in your url? is it just a "visual" problem, or does cause any other problems...

Comment: It's visual but also for SEO because I google also get this prefix. If there is no way to remove this, I would swicht the plugin. :(

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin/theme, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum

Comment: The support isn't that good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the plugin again and this url var doesn't seem to appear. Yea it's very strange because I don't really change somthing - so it just seem to be a bug of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

the plugin author at one time commented this:

> This issue (caused by limitations in WordPress multi site that prevent
>   the easy detection of the blog receiving a request)

are you running multi-site?

Put this in the theme_setup() function inside functions.php:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'repeat=w3tc') !== false) {
 $uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $queryString = '';
 if (isset($uri[1])) {
  $queryString = trim(str_replace('repeat=w3tc', '', $uri[1]), '&');
  $queryString = (!empty($queryString)) ? '?' . $queryString : '';
 }
 wp_redirect(home_url($uri[0] . $queryString), 301);
 exit;
}
```

see if it stops it.

Comment: Yes I'm running a multsite. The code give me this error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Maybee because of the SSL redirects